# how to make a function that executes an event click on jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to know in what way I can implement a function to my code so I do not have to repeat it at every moment.

My Code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //alert('test');
    $("#txt1").css('display', 'none');
    $("#txt2").css('display', 'none');

    $("#titu1").click(function(ev){
     $("#txt1").slideToggle('slow');
    });
    
    $("#titu2").click(function(ev){
     $("#txt2").slideToggle('slow');
    });
});
```

```css
body {
  
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
.txtTituCaracteristica {color:#be1521;}
.arrowBlack {color: #000;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<br />

<div id="titu1" class="txtTituCaracteristica">
  <strong>Living</strong> <span class="arrowBlack"><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></span>
</div>
<div id="txt1" class="txtEachCaracteristica">LoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLorem</div>
<br>

<div id="titu2" class="txtTituCaracteristica"><strong>Stand</strong> <span class="arrowBlack"><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></span></div>
<div id="txt2" class="txtEachCaracteristica">LoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLorem</div>
```

My question is because if I have 50 or 1000 toggle texts, I must do 50 and 1000 separate functions that do the same.

I wish not to repeat so much code

Comment: Why don't you use classes instead of id's

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use classes and the `next` function

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //alert('test');
  $(".txtEachCaracteristica").css('display', 'none');


  $(".txtTituCaracteristica").click(function(ev) {
    $(this).next(".txtEachCaracteristica").slideToggle('slow');
  });


});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.txtTituCaracteristica {
  color: #be1521;
}

.arrowBlack {
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<br />

<div class="txtTituCaracteristica">
  <strong>Living</strong> <span class="arrowBlack"><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></span>
</div>
<div class="txtEachCaracteristica">LoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLorem</div>
<br>

<div class="txtTituCaracteristica"><strong>Stand</strong> <span class="arrowBlack"><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></span></div>
<div class="txtEachCaracteristica">LoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLorem</div>
```

Comment: Edited answer to make answer inline with _existing_ CSS _classes_

Comment: Wooo!! I forgot that I can use this and a class to refer to several elements that contain the same class. I'll be more attentive next time, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use classes instead of Id's

```
$(".txt").click(function(ev){
    $(this).slideToggle('slow');//here this will slide the currently clicked class
});


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<br />

<div  class=" txt txtTituCaracteristica">
  <strong>Living</strong> <span class="arrowBlack"><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></span>
</div>
<div class="txt" class="txtEachCaracteristica">LoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLorem</div>
<br>

<div class="txt xtTituCaracteristica"><strong>Stand</strong> <span class="arrowBlack"><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></span></div>
<div class="txt txtEachCaracteristica">LoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLorem 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Use another class for all the top level divs(titu1, titu2, ....)
Ans see the modification of your code below - 

HTML:
<div id="titu1" class="menuToggle txtTituCaracteristica">
  <strong>Living</strong> <span class="arrowBlack"><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></span>
  <div id="txt1" class="txtEachCaracteristica">LoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLorem</div>
</div>

<br>

<div id="titu2" class="menuToggle txtTituCaracteristica"><strong>Stand</strong> <span class="arrowBlack"><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></span>
<div id="txt2" class="txtEachCaracteristica">LoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLorem</div>
</div>

CSS:
body {

  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
.txtTituCaracteristica {color:#be1521;}
.arrowBlack {color: #000;}

JS:
$(document).ready(function() {
  //alert('test');
    $("#txt1").css('display', 'none');
    $("#txt2").css('display', 'none');

    $(".menuToggle").click(function(ev){
      $(this).children('div').slideToggle('slow');

    });   

});

See Demo: [JSFiddle][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't have to repeat yourself over and over, just use the classes you already have to trigger the events on all elements with that class:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //alert('test');
    $(".txtEachCaracteristica").css('display', 'none');

    $(".txtTituCaracteristica").click(function(ev){
      let id = ev.target.id.substring(ev.target.id.length-1);
     $("#txt"+id).slideToggle('slow');
    });
});
```

```css
body {
  
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
.txtTituCaracteristica {color:#be1521;}
.arrowBlack {color: #000;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<br />

<div id="titu1" class="txtTituCaracteristica">
  <strong>Living</strong> <span class="arrowBlack"><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></span>
</div>
<div id="txt1" class="txtEachCaracteristica">LoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLorem</div>
<br>

<div id="titu2" class="txtTituCaracteristica"><strong>Stand</strong> <span class="arrowBlack"><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></span></div>
<div id="txt2" class="txtEachCaracteristica">LoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLorem</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I only need to handle the click in the text, it only works when you click on the div

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS `[attribute^=value]` Selector. And Set a click event on all  elements that have a `id` attribute value that begins with `"titu"`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //alert('test');
    $( 'div[id^="txt"]' ).css( 'display', 'none' );

    $( 'div[id^="titu"]' ).click( function () {
     $( this ).next( 'div' ).slideToggle( 'slow' );
    });
});
```

```css
body {
  
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
.txtTituCaracteristica {color:#be1521;}
.arrowBlack {color: #000;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<br />

<div id="titu1" class="txtTituCaracteristica">
  <strong>Living</strong> <span class="arrowBlack"><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></span>
</div>
<div id="txt1" class="txtEachCaracteristica">LoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLorem</div>
<br>

<div id="titu2" class="txtTituCaracteristica"><strong>Stand</strong> <span class="arrowBlack"><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></span></div>
<div id="txt2" class="txtEachCaracteristica">LoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLorem</div>
```